# Cannot get return value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, cefsharp

I already succeed using [this](https://gist.github.com/amaitland/9d354376960b0cd9305a#file-oneplusone-cs).

But in this case I need pass the parameter and get return value in one time from javascript using this method. But this code is not working:

```
int idx=1;
chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(
   string.Format(@"
    var i = {0};
    return i;
", idx)
).ContinueWith(x =>
{
   var response = x.Result;

   if (response.Success && response.Result != null)
   {
       this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
       {
           int atemp = (int)response.Result;
           MessageBox.Show(atemp.ToString());
       });
   }
});
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is that your JavaScript code should be a [self invoking function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Try rewriting the function to something like this:

```
(function() {
  var i = 1;
  return i;
})()
```

```js
console.log((function() {
  var i = 1;
  return i;
})());
```

As you can see from the snippet above, this code actually returns a value. You can use this JavaScript in your C# like this:

```
int idx = 1;
chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(
    string.Format(@"
        (function() {{
          var i = {0};
          return i;
        }})()
    ", idx)
).ContinueWith(x =>
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo, I have changed "int i = 0" become "int idx = 0"
Actually, I want to pass the value using variable in c# not harcode by value directly.

Thaks for your response

Comment: @rizkidzulkarnain You don't need to hard code the value to use a self invoking JavaScript function. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have try code as your suggestion, but there is an error message like this :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @rizkidzulkarnain Have you tried debugging? Do you know what line is causing the error? What was your original error? I can't help unless you provide more information.

Comment: yes I have debugged
May be picture in this link can give you more information 

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9gbtJvHeKrCYTF4WjFfQ0VGZm8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The issue with the above example is that the curly braces in the function directly clash with how String.Format() works, they need to be escaped in Microsoft fashion, which is to double them. It should look like this: 

(function() {{
          var i = {0};
          return i;
        }})()